# Is it better to use a pointer instead of returning a value?

Tags: c, pointers, return-value

I was wondering what is the best way to get a value from a function.
A function can return a value like an int for example.
But you can also change the value of a variable with a pointer passed as a parameter to the function.
See below, two examples of codes that do this in two different ways, but produce the same result.

```c
int example_return()
{
    return (1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int value;

    value = example_return();
}
```

```c
void    example_ptr(int *a)
{
    *a = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    int value;

    example_ptr(&value);
}
```

Is there a real difference between the two options, which is the best way?

Comment: Both alternatives are used in practice, sometimes by the same function.  Yes, there is a difference between returning a value and directly writing to an object: for one thing, a function return value can be used directly in an expression, but there can be only per function call.  Neither is best.  Each has its uses.

Comment: Sometimes (eg [`time()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html)) both options are used for one function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side effects should be avoided if not absolutely needed. If you can return the value - return it. Basically, the function should a black-box which does something with parameters and returns the value.

Why:

1. It is much safer. You definitely will not invoke undefined behaviour.
2. It helps the compiler to optimize the code.

In your example -

```
int example_return(void)
{
    return (1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your purpose, If you have a pointer to data, then you have two levels of memory access. First to load an address from the pointer and second to actually load the data. If you simply directly reference a variable, there is only one level of memory access.

**there are some advantages of using pointers ( Memory sharing, Runtime-sized data structures, and Resizable data structures).
most of the time pointers reduce the complexity of a program.**